# Simple Calculator program java

Tags: java, object, calculator, abstract

I'm supposed to create a program which simulates a very simple calculator

So I have been asked to implement an abstract class that represents binary (having 2 arguments) arithmetic expression. I've also made 4 subclasses - division, addition, etc.

However, i need to use these classes to  be
"able to represent any arbitrary expression (i.e. an expression with an arbitrary number of
terms), for example an expression like `(5.0+8.1)*(2.0)` or `((5.0+8.1)*(2.0))/12.5` as quoted by my crswork spec.

In other words, my calculator must be able to use any arithmetic expression.

Pls help.

```
public abstract class ArithmeticExpression { // base abstract superclass

    double left;
    double right;
    double result;

    public abstract void evaluate();

    public abstract void display();
}

// ------------------------------------ Addition subclassed from base class

public class Addition extends ArithmeticExpression {

    public Addition(double x, double y) {
        this.left = x;
        this.right = y;
    }

    @Override
    public void evaluate() {
        result = left + right;
    }

    @Override
    public void display() {

        System.out.println

        ("The expression and result is: " + left + " + " + right + " = "
                + result);

    }

}

// ------------------------------------ Subtract subclassed from base class

public class Subtract extends ArithmeticExpression {

    public Subtract(double x, double y) {
        this.left = x;
        this.right = y;
    }

    @Override
    public void evaluate() {
        result = left - right;
    }

    @Override
    public void display() {

        System.out.println

        ("The expression and result is: " + left + " - " + right + " = "
                + result);

    }

}

// ------------------------------------ Mulitplication subclassed from base
// class

public class Multiplication extends ArithmeticExpression {

    public Multiplication(double x, double y) {
        this.left = x;
        this.right = y;
    }

    @Override
    public void evaluate() {
        result = left * right;
    }

    @Override
    public void display() {

        System.out.println

        ("The expression and result is: " + left + " * " + right + " = "
                + result);

    }

}

// ------------------------------------ Division subclassed from base class

public class Division extends ArithmeticExpression {

    public Division(double x, double y) {
        this.left = x;
        this.right = y;
    }

    @Override
    public void evaluate() {
        result = left / right;
    }

    @Override
    public void display() {

        System.out.println("The expression and result is: " + left + " / "
                + right + " = " + result);

    }

}
```

this is my attampt at making evaluate method return value. Does it work?

```
public abstract ArithmeticExpression evaluate(); 

//------------------------------------  Addition subclassed from base class

public class Addition extends ArithmeticExpression {

public Addition(double x, double y) {
this.left = x;
this.right = y;
}

@Override
public ArithmeticExpression evaluate() {     
result = left + right; 
return this;
}
```

Comment: Some hints: parse from right to left; find the inner most operation based on parenteses and start there; define your parsing code recursively.

Comment: What course are you taking? This almost certainly asks for a syntax tree parser. The expression string gets parsed before calling the 4 basic computations you implemented.

Comment: Taking computer science. is that what i should do? parse the expression string? And how?

Comment: Classes to represent any expression doesn't mean that you should parse, however, it would be nice if you can add this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you need composing your Arithmetic Expressions...

Add a base class for `Arithmetic Expression`, named `Expression` and add a method, `getValue()`.

`WrapperExpression` should extend Expression and must have only one double property that will be returned via getValue(). Now, your Arithmetic Expression subclasses will have an Expression as left and right property, and in your evaluate method, you will call `left.getValue() + right.getValue()` for addition.

Example for `(2 + 8) * 10 + 2`

```
Expression wrap2 = new WrapperExpression(2);
// similar, wrap8, wrap10
Expression add2p8 = new Addition(wrap2, wrap8);
Expression add2p8m10 = new Multiplication(add2p8, wrap10);
Expression add2p8m10p2 = new Addition(add2p8m10, wrap2);
```

Hope that helps.

Edit:
Expression should be an abstract class(you should not be able to do Expression ex = new Expression(); ) or even an interface:

```
public abstract class Expression {

  // override this method in your subclasses, WrapperExpression, Addition and so on
  public abstract double getValue();

}
```

Comment: Could u pls show me what the expression class would look like, and how i should implement getValue in my subclasses (without the example numbers). Thx in advance

Comment: sorry for repeatedly bothering you, but could u pls show me what the WrapperExpression class will look like?

Comment: It will have only one `double` property, you will set this property via `constructor` and in the `getValue`, you will return it. And of course, it will extend the `Expression` class.

Answer (score 0):

Without getting too overly difficult you could just overload your constructors so that they can handle other Arithmetic Expressions:

```
public class Division extends ArithmeticExpression {

public Division(ArithmeticExpression x, ArithmeticExpression y) {
this.left = x.evaluate();
this.right = y.evaluate();
}
```

That way you can use your existing classes and reference each other to create compounded expressions.

EDIT - Although now that I think about it this doesn't allow for Order of Operations. For that you'll need to create a tree hiearchy.

Comment: Valid solution if and only if evaluate returns something.

Comment: Good Point... why isn't evaluate returning something?

Comment: He's probably a newbie, he will figure it out :)